# Ruby version of the TCL-based Expect?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, tcl, expect

Expect seems to be a very powerful automation tool: http://www.nist.gov/mel/msid/expect.cfm

Is there a Ruby equivalent to that tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`pty`](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/pty/rdoc/index.html) package in the standard library, but that only implements a subset of the functionality of the Tcl package. In particular, it appears to lack the ability to wait for many patterns at once, or to provide interaction at the same time. Maybe this won't matter for what you're doing with it; a great many expect programs never make use of its full power.

Comment: It's also really badly documented; if I didn't already know the Tcl package somewhat I'd find it really hard to understand the Ruby package.

Comment: Agree..the documentation is not good at all.